# Adding an item to many to many after creation in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Recently I've been trying to do something with this.
Think of the family as a facebook group.

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owned_families')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='families', blank=True)
```

#### let's assume we have this family object called `fm`, for illustration purpose.

My problem is, The `owner` is one of the `users` right? I mean, When someone creates a family, He's now the owner right? he owns it but he's still a user listed in it's users list.
Now, when I create a new family `fm` , I want to add the `fm.owner` to `fm.users`.

Let's talk about what I've tried.

- `post_save` signal doesn't work with m2m. ***X***
- `m2m_changed` happens when the field is changed, not created. ***X***
- Overriding `save` method, lemme illustrate what I tried to acheive. ***?***

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old = self.pk
        super(Family, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if old is None:
            print('This actually shows up')
            self.users.add(self.owner)
```

Basically, this saves the pk each time, First time a family is created, Before calling `super.....` it has no `.pk` so I'm counting on this to check if it had no pk (On creation).

The problem is `self.users.add(self.owner)` doesn't work.

I've tried to clone the object as whole and keep track of it like

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old = self
        super(Family, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if old is None:
            print("This actually doesn't show up")
            self.users.add(self.owner)
```

This actually is terrible, It takes a *refernce* to self and when calling `super....`, The `self`and it's reference `old` gets mutated, I just wanted to show this as this question itself might solve someone's problem.

So I solved this by.

```
import copy
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old = copy.deepcopy(self)
        super(Family, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if old is None:
            print('This actually shows up')
            self.users.add(self.owner)
```

but `self.users.add(self.owner)` still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: What error do you get with `self.users.add(self.owner)`?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: `post_save` can be used just as well since you want to add the the owner when the the family is created/saved. If you you want to check if the owner is removed from the users, you can connect to the `m2m_changed` signal. The only sensible approach listed here is the first one: `self.pk` should be `None` on the first save attempt. Unless you are not showing the full code, e.g. if family had a `UUIDField` as pk.

Comment: This is the full code, And `post_save` doesn't work with m2m relations

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, but all of them don't work, This is the problem, Something prevents .users.add from working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that in the django admin, the instance is saved first, and only *after* that the inline formsets and m2m-fields are saved. If the owner is not in there, it will be removed.
You can override some functionality in the admin to remedy this:

```
class FamilyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(FamilyAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        form.instance.users.add(form.instance.owner)
```

Furthermore, you can try (note that there are other ways to remove the owner that are not picked up by any signal or other hook) to prevent code from removing the owner:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Family.users.through)
def famliy_users_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    family = kwargs['instance']
    pk_set = kwargs['pk_set']
    action = kwargs['action']
    if action == "pre_add":
        pk_set.add(family.owner_id)
    if action == "pre_remove":
        pk_set.remove(family.owner_id)
    if action == "post_clear":
        family.users.add(family.owner)
```

But generally speaking, you are jumping through those hoops because you are denormalizing your data (putting the owner in users makes that information redundant, forcing you to keep your data correct). Since you always know the owner is one of the users, why not wrap that in a method

```
class Family(...):
    # ...
    def members(self):
        return User.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=self.users.all()|Q(pk=self.owner_id)))
```

and access family members through that method?