# what is the correct way to override the save method in django?

Tags: django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I have an image model where I can upload images and I want to optimize them with pillow, I did that but there is three problems:

1. the images doesn't get saved in the correct folder.
2. django has a feature when there is two files with the same name django adds a random string to its name but now with two images with the same name only one gets uploaded.
3. the original images gets uploaded too.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])])
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        im = Image.open(self.image1).convert('RGB')
        im2 = Image.open(self.image2).convert('RGB')
        im.save(self.image1.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75)
        im2.save(self.image2.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75)
        super(Images, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The code itself is ok, However, `Images` model is not good, You can create something like

I'll fix this *STRUCTURE-WISE* first.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    my_other_model = models.ForeignKey(MyOtherModel, ..., related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/',
                              validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=
                                                        ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']
                                                      )])
```

Now, each `MyOtherModel` instance has `.images` and you can create as many images as you want instead of just 2.

Back on topic.. If this is working for you it's correct, *HOWEVER*, There's more than django involved, Lemme explain

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        im = Image.open(self.image1).convert('RGB') # open image1, Put it in RAM
        im2 = Image.open(self.image2).convert('RGB') # open image2, Put it in RAM
        im.save(self.image1.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image1
        im2.save(self.image2.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image2
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # easier syntax for python3
```

Now, I want you to compare the one above with the one below.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        im = Image.open(self.image1).convert('RGB') # open image1, Put it in RAM
        im.save(self.image1.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image1
        img.close() # remove from RAM
        im2 = Image.open(self.image2).convert('RGB') # open image2, Put it in RAM
        im2.save(self.image2.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image2
        im2.close() # remove from RAM
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # easier syntax for python3
```

However, This is still wrong. Because each time it's saved, It will do all of this again, You only want to do this on the first save, On the model creation, right? If so.. Read on.

Fixing this *CODE-WISE*

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old_pk = self.pk # pk is created on saving, We didn't call super().save() yet!
        # so the pk should be None if this is the creation phase.

        if old_pk is None:
            im = Image.open(self.image1).convert('RGB') # open image1, Put it in RAM
            im.save(self.image1.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image1
            im1.close() # remove from RAM
            im2 = Image.open(self.image2).convert('RGB') # open image2, Put it in RAM
            im2.save(self.image2.path,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75) # process image2, remove from RAM
            im2.close() # remove from RAM
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # easier syntax for python3
```

I've mentioned this in a question before, Reading the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801443/adding-an-item-to-many-to-many-after-creation-in-django) is enough for you to get the point

*NOTES:*

- If you want to process both images at the same time, You need to look at multiprocessing or threading or use celery.
- `FileExtensionValidator` is not enough to know the file type.
- Use a context manager when dealing with files, Search for `with as` expression.

The second problem is that you're not actually opening the image, open the image using `Images.image1.path`, This is why the original images are uploaded.

Add your `MEDIA_ROOT` in the question please.

For a good way of how to handle resizing images, See [this](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2018/12/django-how-to-editmanipulate-uploaded-images-on-the-fly-before-saving/)

Comment: your code is very logical thanks a lot for taking the time to write this, I will definitely follow all your suggestions and notes. I tried this `Image.open(self.image2.path)` but it says `No such file or directory` and I tried without `.path` and it didn't give me an error but the same problems of before stayed. and Ramadhan Karim bro

Comment: Ops, My bad, .path doesn't provide the full path, It's right as is, I think you should use .file or .read or .open('mode')

Comment: I'll test and tell you soon

Comment: did you find something? or should I just optimize the pictures in the client side?

Comment: I think [this](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2018/12/django-how-to-editmanipulate-uploaded-images-on-the-fly-before-saving/) should work

Comment: جزاك الله خيرا, و رمضان كريم. this is what I wanted

Comment: Thanks, for you too, Mark as answered if you got your answer