# Django - update ForeignKey when new object is created

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update my Foreign Key when the image is added to the database, just simply to tag the image if height is greater then width and vice versa. To do so I am trying to override the save method but I dont know how to do it exactly.

models:

```
from PIL import Image

class PhotoDimensionsCategory(models.Model):
     photo_dim_category = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class ImageInGallery(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
     gallery_dim = models.ForeignKey(PhotoDimensionsCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        on_height = PhotoDimensionsCategory.objects.get(photo_dim_category='on_height')
        on_width = PhotoDimensionsCategory.objects.get(photo_dim_category='on_width')
        is_new = not self.pk

        if img.height > img.width and is_new:
               # set the gallery_dim to on_height
        else
               # set the gallery_dim to on_width
```

I tried few things, but it ended in errors. Any ideas. Thanks.

EDIT:

If I try to use signals it wont do anything:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ImageInGallery)
def set_dim(sender, instance, created, **kwardgs):
if created:
    instance.gallery_dim.photo_dim_category = 'on_height'
    instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are "signals" in django that you can call when an object is modified or created:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=ImageInGallery)
def set_dim(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        PhotoDimensionsCategory.objects.create(...)
    else:
        instance.gallery_dim = ...
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Comment: Well I tried to use signals but it wont do anything. I added the code on my initial post.

Comment: Make sure your import is correct, also you try and put a print line before "if created" and print out all the arguments (or debug it).
I think you should probably call `instance.gallery_dim.save()`

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623638/what-is-the-correct-way-to-override-the-save-method-in-django/61623845#61623845), however
this is what you're looking for

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old_pk = self.pk # pk is created on saving, We didn't call super().save() yet!
        # so the pk should be None if this is the creation phase.

        if old_pk is None:
            # do something, Only at the first save 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Signals can help, but they're harder to debug.

Comment: This structure may work too, but you need to put the save() before the "if" since the OP ask for a post-save operation. Also, you'll need an extra query to get the object that is being saved.

Comment: @Barney Wops, I thought it's before save, But yea you're right